# f.association with WHERE clause for collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

In my form I have a f.association field:

```
<%= f.association :groups, as: :check_boxes %>
```

Now, I get a list of check boxes with all groups that are in my database. I would like to show only some of the groups using a where filter.

```
<%= f.association :groups,  Group.where(type: 'products'), as: :check_boxes %>
```

But this does not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Might be worth noting this is more of a formtastic question than a Rails question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formtastic should allow you to define the collection with the `:collection` key.

```
<%= f.association :groups, as: :check_boxes, collection: Group.where(type: 'products') %>
```

More examples can be found in their codebase [here](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/inputs/check_boxes_input.rb#L39)